# Concise way of getting or creating an object with given field values

Tags: django

Suppose I have:

```
from django.db import models

class MyContentClass(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    another_field = models.TextField()

x = MyContentClass(content="Hello, world!", another_field="More Info")
```

Is there a more concise way to perform the following logic?

```
existing = MyContentClass.objects.filter(content=x.content, another_field=x.another_field)
if existing:
    x = existing[0]
else:
    x.save()
# x now points to an object which is saved to the DB,
# either one we've just saved there or one that already existed
# with the same field values we're interested in.
```

Specifically:

1. Is there a way to query for both (all) fields without specifying
   each one separately?
2. Is there a better idiom for either getting the old object or saving the new one? Something like `get_or_create`, but which accepts an object as a parameter?

Assume the code which does the saving is separate from the code which generates the initial `MyContentClass` instance which we need to compare to. This is typical of a case where you have a function which returns a model object without also saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert x to a dictionary with

```
x_data = x.__dict__
```

Then that could be passed into the object's get_or_create method.

```
MyContentClass.objects.get_or_create(**x_data)
```

The problem with this is that there are a few fields that will cause this to error out (eg the unique ID, or the _state Django modelstate field). However, if you pop() those out of the dictionary beforehand, then you'd probably be good to go :)

```
cleaned_dict = remove_unneeded_fields(x_data)
MyContentClass.objects.get_or_create(**cleaned_dict)

def remove_unneeded_fields(x_data):
    unneeded_fields = [
        '_state',
        'id',
        # Whatever other fields you don't want the new obj to have
        # eg any field marked as 'unique'
    ]
    for field in unneeded_fields:
        del x_data[field]
    return x_data
```

**EDIT**
To avoid issues associated with having to maintain a whitelist/blacklist of fields you, could do something like this:

```
def remove_unneeded_fields(x_data, MyObjModel):
    cleaned_data = {}
    for field in MyObjModel._meta.fields:
        if not field.unique:
            cleaned_data[field.name] = x_data[field.name]
    return cleaned_Data
```

There would probably have to be more validation than simply checking that the field is not unique, but this might offer some flexibility when it comes to minor model field changes.

Comment: I like the idea but scared of future incompatibility when more private fields are added :(

Comment: A fair concern. You could whitelist the fields you want inside of the remove_unneeded_fields function instead. But then we're back to listing out the fields you want (which is contrary to your attempt at being concise).

Hmm... editing with something else that might be of use

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a custom manager for those models and add the functions you want to do with the models (like a custom get_or_create function).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

This would be the cleanest way and involves no hacking. :)

You can create specific managers for specific models or create a superclass with functions you want for all models.

If you just want to add a second manager with a different name, beware that it will become the default manager if you don't set the `objects` manager first (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#default-managers)